# The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly error XA2006

Tags: android, xamarin, compilation, linker

I have tried to skip the System.Configuration package when linking but still no luck.

I can compile the code and run it without issue for debug but when I go to compile as release build - using linker (sdk assemblies only) this is what i get.

Here is the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006:
>   Could not resolve reference to
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationException' (defined in assembly
>   'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') with scope 'System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. When the scope is
>   different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type
>   is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationException    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference
>   reference)    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference
>   reference)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition
>   assembly)    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger,
>   LinkContext& context)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception
>   innerException, String message, Object[] args)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() PostASelfiePOC.Droid    C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets  1812

Answer (score 0):

You check Enable Multi-dex option checked and also delete your bin and obj folder

And clean and rebuild your code and build i hope it will be help you

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you but unfortunately this has not worked.